# Current location in Offline Indoor Navigation in ios

Tags: ios, ibeacon, mapbox, indoor-positioning-system

As a part of my ibeacon based ios application i have to find the current location of the user in my indoor map offline, I am using mapbox SDK for displaying my offline indoor map there is any way to calculate the user location with the help of near by beacons.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes!  You can use Radius Networks' [NavigationKit](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/navigationkit/) framework** to do offline indoor navigation. There is a reference app that shows you how to use it with an image-based map, but you can modify it to work with mapbox as well.  Best of all, NavigationKit is free to use on deployments of up to 100 mobile devices.

Comment: Now i am trying navigationkit framework for my application,But i didn't get any documentation  or tutorials for reference application .

Comment: How i will get navigationkit.plist for my own map image from radius network now i am stuck with it.

Comment: The framework is in pre-release, so for now, you can send us an image marked up with your beacon locations as described here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/navigationkit/getting_started.html.  You can send this to support@radiusnetworks.com