# Custom Maps for IOS with Navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dictionary, ios9

I want a native IOS app with custom offline maps for a certain residential location like a group of buildings OR a large resort, app will be limited to these type of small areas only. With the app users can navigate from one apartment to another and can also see map of all the apartments/flats.

In case of resorts customers can be able to move from lobby to restaurant and then to swimming pool, etc with navigation from the app. They can also see the map of all available locations in the resort and can navigate to any of them through the app.

I am not sure from where to start to accomplish this task. Can anyone please suggest me some SDK OR anything from where I can start working on this app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't :/

You will probably have to store your places maps in your own format.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using google maps street view. you need to integrate google map SDK in your IOS application and implement the 3D street view.

Check out this links:

1) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview 
2) https://www.google.com/maps/streetview/#
3) http://thenextweb.com/google/2015/09/03/googles-new-street-view-app-lets-you-upload-your-own-360-images/

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is nothing more than **Offline Navigation**  ios doesn't have any sdk support to this, but you can achieve this by

- using Ibeacons (bluetooth low energy devices)
- using wifi triangulation

in both the cases you need to do lots of calculations like trilaterations and it doesn't have any guarantee for the accuracy the following links may help you all the best
[beacons for indoor navigations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863372/current-location-in-offline-indoor-navigation-in-ios)

sdk

- [radious network](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/navigationkit/)
- [estimote](http://developer.estimote.com/)